# Google checkstyle configuration is failing on an Android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, checkstyle

I'm trying to use Checkstyle on an Android project. I figured Googles java coding conventions would be good to use. I'm getting an error when parsing this file:

https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

I've looked this error up on stack overflow and it has come up once before, [How to compile project with Google Checkstyle rules with gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749804/how-to-compile-project-with-google-checkstyle-rules-with-gradle)

It seems the error is an older version of checkstyle is pulled down when using gradle. So my question is, is there just an older checkstyle configuration file I can use that's made for the current version of checkstyle pulled down by gradle? Should I even be using Googles java guidelines for an Android project? Is there a better default file to work with? I really don't want to import a new version of checkstyle into my project as mentioned in the answer of the other SO question.

Comment: Take a look at my [config](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/gradle/code_quality.gradle). They bundled google_check on my request so I could do this.

Comment: The question is not so clear. You can define a checkstyle task in each project (it requires a xml file inside each project). Otherwise you can import the AOSP codestyle for AS from (https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/ide/intellij/codestyles) and let the IDE do the work for you.

Comment: The link in @BenManes comment is broken

Comment: @EdmundJohnson Too bad SO doesn't rewrite links to be hash specific. Here is a corrected [link](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/6ccd359fe45efc1e69f049f0465e0c146864b475/gradle/codeQuality.gradle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always specify the exact version of Checkstyle that you want to use. The Checkstyle guys often make breaking changes which would fail your build unless you set a specific fixed version. For example:

```
checkstyle {
    configFile file('downloaded_google_checks.xml')
    toolVersion '6.9'    // set Checkstyle version here
    showViolations = true
}
```

Then, you can also use the right configuration file for your version, for example: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/checkstyle-6.9/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml. Note the version number in the URL - this can be adjusted to the version you selected in your Gradle config.

Do not use the latest configuration file from the master branch, as this matches the current code on the master branch (which is not released yet).

The above allows you to adjust the configuration as necessary. If you are certain that you want the original rule file, you may also follow @BenMane's suggestion from his comment, which is to reference the bundled google_checks.xml directly.